# Hatch brush style in android

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, paint

I need help with drawing hatched rectangle on canvas (diagonal stroke).
Now I cant find out no other way than make it manually.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a hatching pattern on a small bitmap, and use that with a [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html). There's a sample in `ApiDemos/graphics`, called `Pattern.java` that shows you how to do it. Although, if you only need to draw a hatched rectangle, it might be easier to just do the hatching there manually.

Answer (score 0):

To create a shader as suggested by @svdree, we need a repeatable hatching section like this:

[image: hatching section]

For any given line rotated by 45°, its horizontal or vertical crossing takes `hypot = √(thickness² + thickness²)`. Any edge contains exactly two lines, thus we need a square Bitmap of `2×hypot` size.

According to the picture, whiter lines come from `0, hypot/2` to `hypot/2, 0` and from `hypot/2, size` to `size, hypot/2`. To make the lines go to the end of bounds, SQUARE Cap can be used.

Putting all this together, here's the code:

```kotlin
fun Hatching45Shader(@Px lineWidth: Int, @ColorInt background: Int, @ColorInt lineColor: Int): Shader {
    val hypot = hypot(lineWidth.toDouble(), lineWidth.toDouble()).toInt()
    val bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(hypot + hypot, hypot + hypot, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    bm.eraseColor(background)
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        strokeWidth = lineWidth.toFloat()
        color = lineColor
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.SQUARE
    }
    Canvas(bm).apply {
        val half = hypot / 2f
        drawLine(0f, half, half, 0f, paint)
        val size = (hypot + hypot).toFloat()
        drawLine(half, size, size, half, paint)
    }
    return BitmapShader(bm, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT)
}
```

P. S. If `lineColor` is translucent, it will blend with `background`. This is intentional.